Ubuntu 24.10 in Oracle VMBox - missing Processor command avx512
I use Ubuntu in the Oracle VMBox. After the update to 24.10, I receive the following error message when I run the programs created with Gtk4:
'-avx512er' is not a recognized feature for this target (ignoring feature)

As far as I understand this, this is a problem that lies in the command set of the processor.
less /proc/cpuinfo | grep avx

confirms that this processor command is actually missing. My host system is Ubuntu 24.04 and has this command. So it is not passed through by Oracle VMBox? Or is it on Ubuntu 24.10.?
My processor is:  11th Gen Intel® Core™ i9-11900 × 8
Someone has an idea of how this problem can be solved.

Your processor does have AVX512, but in the VM settings you probably emulate a much older processor. You can set it to pass through or something like that, so you can use the features from your cpu

@sleepyhead I have the same problem. I have not found a way to "to pass through" in VirtualBox settings.

Virtualbox has a cmdline to modify the cpuprofile and cpuidset. VBoxManage list cpu-profiles, vboxmanage list hostcpuids, vboxmanage modifyvm "${vm}" --cpu-profile host,
vboxmanage modifyvm "${vm}" --cpuid-set 00000001
